Bin file in ZYBO FPGA (boot from SPI)
I am new to Zynq architecture. I want to run counter on ZYBO. I run it on PL using JTAG just by generating bitstream.
Now I want to create mcs/bin file and want to store it in QSPI and want my board to work standalone (run counter when powered on without need of bitstream again). When I upload my bin file on Spansion SPI Vivado gives an error of FSBL file.
What is FSBL file??? Do I need FSBL file for Zynq architecture, or it is also required for any 7 series FPGA (Nexys 4 DDR)?

Yes, you need to generate an FSBL (first stage boot loader) file for the Zynq.
The Zynq is different from other 7-series devices in that it has a pair of Arm processors and a bunch of peripherals in "hard logic" (the Processor Subsystem, or PS) in addition to the programmable logic (PL). Because of this, the boot process is different — The PS has a boot ROM that reads the boot mode pins, which allows it to identify the external boot memory device and load software (the FSBL) into on-chip memory (OCM) and then execute it. It is the FSBL that finds and loads the PL bitstream file from the boot memory.
So, even if you don't have any application code to run on the PS, you still need to use Vitis to generate the FSBL that loads the bitstream into the PL.
If you do end up running application code on the PS, then the FSBL will also perform additional housekeeping functions, such as configuring the DDR controller and bringing up any external storage not supported by the boot ROM, before loading either your program or your OS's second stage boot loader.
